# Jquery moving bar and stopping 0-100

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find the right way to go about this i am trying to get a bar that move from 0 - 100 and you got a stop button and when you press it the bar will stop and display a number. i am trying to do this in jquery.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Nested elements (outer = frame, inner = bar w/ width in percentage of frame) could be a way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of [jQuery.animate()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate) and [jQuery.stop()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/stop). Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), just copy'n'paste'n'run it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2058493</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#progress .bar').animate({ width: '100%' }, 5000);
                $('#stop').click(function() { 
                    $('#count').text($('#progress .bar').stop().width());
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            #progress {
                width: 100px;
                height: 20px;
                border: 1px black solid;
            }
            .bar {
                width: 0%;
                height: 20px;
                background: #00c;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="progress"><div class="bar"></div></div>
        <button id="stop">stop</button>
        <span id="count"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that the width is in pixels. If you change the bar's width in CSS, then you'll need to do some basic math to get it in percents in the `span`.

Comment: Thank you works great

can i just ask for 1 more thing can you get the bar to keep looping?